# ASPXGridView (devexpress) Hyperlink column sorting

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a DevExpress ASPx GridView control and am trying to implement sorting for the grid columns.

The gridView contains has integer values in one column, text in the rest. I also have a column which contains hyperlinks and is added through the code behind during run time.

I am using the `Aspxgrid_CustomColumnSort` event for sorting the grid.

I can achieve the sorting for the column which contains the integer values and texts successfully, however the same code is not working for the column with hyperlinks.

When I click on the column header the hyperlinks sorts in ascending order, 
but when I click the header the second time the grid isnt getting sorted in the descending order, the hyperlinks are sorted in randomn order ( neither ascending nor descending)

And, further clicks on the header do not do anything.

Any advice/suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B145444.aspx. In this page, someone had reported an issue using the `GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn`.